# How do i suppress terminal output on ping, but still be able to validate response?

Tags: python

So I've been struggling to suppress my terminal output whenever I send a packet. I just want to validate the response (0,2 or else) so my terminal won't get spammed with the standard "ping statistics, packets received, packet loss". How would I go about doing this code-wise? I'm not looking for a terminal / bash "way".

```
def ping():
    hosts = open('hosts.txt', 'r')
    for host_ip in hosts:
       res = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', host_ip])
       if res == 0:
          print "ping to", host_ip, "OK"
       elif res == 2:
          print "no response from", host_ip
       else:
          print "ping to", host_ip, "failed!"
```

Comment: how about rerouting the output of ping to `/dev/null` or to a file ? `ping www.google.com > /dev/null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pinged to google dns servers using python's `subprocess.Popen` class and it returns nothing to the terminal except the returncode I printed in code

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['ping','-c' ,'1', '8.8.8.8'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
returncode = process.returncode
print(returncode)
```

OUTPUT

```
0
```